# How to animate a square folding in half diagonally in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have a square that I am trying to fold in half in After Effects. I made two squares and masked each one. I then made the bottom half a 3D layer and tried working with the Y and Z rotation. But it isn't working the way I need it to.

Here is a visual for what I am trying to achieve.
Here is the square in the original format:
[image]

The I am trying to fold it on the diagonal but it isn't working.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: grab]

Make a square

Centre the square on screen

Make sure the [anchor point](https://www.schoolofmotion.com/blog/anchor-point-in-after-effects) for the square is exactly at the position where the rotation should take place.

Add a mask revealing half the square

Duplicate the square

Change the colour of the duplicate to make it easier to see what you're doing

Change the mask on square 2 to 'subtract' mode, to reveal the other half

Make both layers 3D

Add a null object (it will be in the centre of the screen)

Make it 3D

Rotate it on the Z axis by 45 degrees

Pair square 2 to the null object

Animate the Y axis on the null object between 0 and -180 degrees.

The lower half of the square will fold up to meet the upper half.